# How to convert array of mappables to JSON?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I using Objectmapper and Alamofire in my project.
Let's have a struct:

```
struct User: Mappable {
  var name = ""

  init?(map: Map) {}

  mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    name <- map["name"]
  }
}
```

and then i want to make a request to send array of users to server like this:

```
var users = [User]()
...
let parameters = ?//i want to convert users array to JSON

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
...
}
```

But i don't know how to convert users array to parameters for input to Alamofire request.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an object to String using mapper:

```
let user = User()
let userString = Mapper<User>.toJSONString(user)
```

To convert it to JSON:

```
let userJSON = Mapper<User>().toJSON(user)
```

You can checkout various apis provided by `ObjectMapper` by command-clicking '`Mapper`' in your code or go to *Mapper.swift*.